# Delete all users from the server with one command

Tags: node.js, discord

Delete all users from the server with one command, how? Usually, a ban is deleted and only a specific user, but how to delete all with one command?

Comment: I need code for this

Comment: What have you tried? If I am understanding correctly, you want to remove every user from a server? Seems like it could only be malicious. I hope you don't have malicious intentions.

Answer (score 0):

Heĺlo, as first, you need to get the guild, where you want to kick/ban every member:

```js
//Get the guild by ID
const guild = client.guilds.get("ID");

//Get the guild where a message was sent
const guild = message.guild;
```

Now if you want to KICK every user in that guild:

```js
//Kick every user in that guild using forEach()
guild.members.forEach(member => member.kick);
```

Or if you want to BAN every user in that guild:

```js
//Ban every user in that guild using forEach()
guild.members.forEach(member => member.ban);
```